# Transparent Navigation Bar for Lollipop app?

Tags: android, xml, themes, android-5.0-lollipop, navigationbar

What do I add to themes.xml to change the navigation bar to be more transparent? I can't find documentation for it anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your theme add the following line:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Romain Guy has published a nice [**sample app**](https://github.com/romainguy/google-io-2014) that uses this API. Maybe it will help. (You might need to refactor some code since the project was originally written using the Android L developer preview).

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: yeah: https://s3.amazonaws.com/pushbullet-uploads/ujAMso2we3U-ATSyIJnoGjnz2yXGftRx0wi6whUje9SS/Screenshot_2014-11-08-18-34-56.png

Comment: I think you can get around that by setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your layout's root view. You can also look at Romain Guy's sample app for an example on how these APIs can be used (see my updated answer).

Comment: That almost worked; it fixed my cut off issues, problem now is that the nav bar is no longer translucent, it is now colored a grayish color.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I can't find a way to make ONLY the NavigationBar transparent and NOT the StatusBar...

Comment: This makes it `Translucent`, how do I make it completely `Transparent`?

Comment: What do you mean by "completely transparent"? Which part is showing up as "not transparent" for you?

Comment: @Kalvn You can use this: `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` to make ONLY the nagivation bar transparent. NOTE: It is very difficult to see the three buttons with a white background.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer is correct. You can use

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Another option is to use

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Awesome! Any reason why my toolbar gets cut off though?

Comment: I don't want to make it translucent is there any other way to solve this problem and also do want to add default padding from bottom.