# Navigiation Bar Color - Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, navigationbar

Can someone please tell me simple instructions on how i can make the Navigation Bar color in Lollipop fully transparent?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Poissible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824305/transparent-navigation-bar-for-lollipop-app?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In your theme add the following line:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Comment: This only made the navigation bar transparent... how can i make the navigation bar fully transparent in Lollipop OS? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the maximum transparency that can you achieve

Comment: Is there a way to set the navigation bar a color? Then I can use 8 digits to make the opacity 0? (i.e. #00000000)? Thanks!